# Conflict between levelspace and the profiler

Tags: netlogo, bytecode

I ran into a problem while trying to use the Netlogo levelspace extension and the profiler space extension in a single model. Linking an interactive model with levelspace and then trying to start the profiler generates an error about requiring the bytecode generator (See full error below). This is true even when I then use `ls:reset` in order to close the interactive model and try to clear all traces of it.

```
extensions [ls profiler]

to test

  ls:reset
  ls:create-interactive-models 1 "./MyRandomOtherModel.nlogo"
  ls:reset

  profiler:start

end
```

Does anyone else have any experience with this interaction and how to circumvent it?

> Extension exception: The profiler extension requires the NetLogo bytecode generator, which is currently turned off. See the org.nlogo.noGenerator property.
> error while observer running PROFILER:START
> called by procedure TEST
> called by Command Center
>
> org.nlogo.nvm.WrappedExtensionException: Extension exception: The profiler extension requires the NetLogo bytecode generator, which is currently turned off. See the org.nlogo.noGenerator property.
> at org.nlogo.prim._extern.perform(_extern.java:40)
> at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.stepConcurrent(Context.java:107)
> at org.nlogo.nvm.ConcurrentJob.step(ConcurrentJob.scala:65)
> at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.runPrimaryJobs(JobThread.scala:133)
> at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.$anonfun$run$1(JobThread.scala:68)
> at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
> at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
> at org.nlogo.api.Exceptions$.handling(Exceptions.scala:41)
> at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.run(JobThread.scala:66)
> Caused by: org.nlogo.api.ExtensionException: The profiler extension requires the NetLogo bytecode generator, which is currently turned off. See the org.nlogo.noGenerator property.
> at org.nlogo.extensions.profiler.ProfilerExtension$ProfilerStart.perform(ProfilerExtension.java:52)
> at org.nlogo.prim._extern.perform(_extern.java:36)
> 8 more
>
> NetLogo 6.3.0
> main: org.nlogo.app.AppFrame
> thread: JobThread
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.3 (BellSoft; 17.0.3+7-LTS)
> operating system: Windows 11 10.0 (amd64 processor)
> Scala version 2.12.16
> JOGL: (3D View not initialized)
> OpenGL Graphics: (3D View not initialized)
> model: profiler test
>
> 08:20:14.493 SwitchedTabsEvent (org.nlogo.app.Tabs) AWT-EventQueue-0
> 08:20:14.483 RuntimeErrorEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$4 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
> 08:20:14.483 PeriodicUpdateEvent (org.nlogo.app.App$$anon$4 (org.nlogo.window.GUIWorkspace)) AWT-EventQueue-0
> 08:20:14.483 WidgetRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.window.ButtonWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
> 08:20:14.483 RemoveJobEvent (org.nlogo.window.ButtonWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
> 08:20:14.483 WidgetRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.widget.NoteWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
> 08:20:14.483 WidgetRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.widget.NoteWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
> 08:20:14.483 WidgetRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.window.PlotWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
> 08:20:14.483 WidgetRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.window.PlotWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0
> 08:20:14.483 WidgetRemovedEvent (org.nlogo.window.SliderWidget) AWT-EventQueue-0

Comment: I think that is this known bug:  https://github.com/NetLogo/LevelSpace/issues/143

Comment: Per that issue, this is now resolved and a new version of LevelSpace has been released to the extensions manager for easy install and use in NetLogo 6.3.

Comment: Thank you for solving this so quickly

Comment: If you write it as a short answer, I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll accept my own update to close out this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was solved and a new version was committed by Jasper rather than me needing a workaround. Updating Netlogo to version 6.3.0 and updating Levelspace to 2.3.4 solves the problem.